# How to get collection of all the widgets created in admin panel?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, widget, magento2.3.4

In admin panel, I create a widget by choosing it's **Type**, **Design Theme**  and applying the custom widget options. I have not selected any **Layout Updates** for that widget.

Let's say I have created ten widgets of the same type in the above mentioned way. Now I want to retrieve this collection of widgets and get their custom options. Is there any way to do it?

Refer this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkyRo.jpg) for images.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking and exploring I came up with this solution:

https://github.com/Mathanagopal97/Get-Widget-Instance-Data

To the experts out there, is there any other way achieve the result other than the one which I used?

Comment: For me this returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Widget's model method "getWidgets()" or "getWidgetsArray()" to get all the widgets:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Widget;

use Magento\Widget\Model\Widget;

class Test
{

    protected $_widget;

    public function __construct(
        Widget $_widget
    )
    {
        $this->_widget = $_widget;
    }

    public function getAllWidgets(): array
    {
        // here you have all the widgets
        $array = $this->_widget->getWidgetsArray();
        
        return $array;
    }
}
```